# How doing a datediff between current and next date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, difference, datediff

I want to do a datediff between two columns as explain in the example:

```
 date 1    date 2
 date 1.1  date 2.1
 date 1.2  date 2.2
 date 1.3  date 2.3
 date 1.4  date 2.4
```

I want to do datediff (date 2.1,date 1.2), datediff (date 2.2,date 1.3)? datediff (date 2.3,date 1.4) ...

Doing the difference between the current of date 2 et the next of date 1.

Any help please?

Comment: Lookup `lead()` in the documentation of your DBMS.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using. I would also help if you provided *actual* data, and the corresponding expected results.

Comment: Tag our question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lag()` or `lead()` . . . it is hard to tell which direction.  But something like this:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(day,
                lag(end_date) over (order by start_date),
                start_date
               ) as dates_between
from t;
```

Comment: Can I do your query per id ? suppose that I have another comlun in the beggening of my table and I want to do this query per id. Is there any way to do it please ?

Comment: @salwa17 . . . Your question doesn't have any `id` in the sample data.  But you can handle that by using `partition by id`.